# Asp.net c#, Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

```
var result = from q in memberDbSet
     select new
     {
         no = q.no,
         fullName = q.firstName + ' ' + q.lastName
     };
```

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only
>   primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.

I got above error, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is linq to entities??

Comment: Not `System.Char`?? And what is `memberDbSet`?

Comment: memberDbSet is IQueryable<member>

Comment: Didn't using a string in stead of char help? I'm surprised...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because the LINQ provider cannot translate the `q.firstName + ' ' + q.lastName` expression to SQL. A work-around for this is to call `AsEnumerable()` to bring the data in memory, and do the rest of your selection there:

```
var result = (from q in memberDbSet /* where clause goes here */)
   .AsEnumerable()
   . Select(q => new {
        no = q.no,
        fullName = q.firstName + ' ' + q.lastName
   });
```

Make sure that you put all filtering into the query prior to `AsEnumerable()` to avoid reading into memory more data than you need.

Comment: `AsEnumerable` is not a real fix, only a workaround that can be applied as a last resort. I believe that in this case the root problem can be fixed though. For the record.

Answer (score 1):

You are concatenating strings and a `char`. Apparently, Entity Framework doesn't like that. Change it into

```
fullName = q.firstName + " " + q.lastName
```

The only thing is, I would have expected

> Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Char'